# Using a Dictionary for Text Mining

Tags: text-mining

I want to use a dictionary to analyze a text with text mining mechanisms.

So I'm looking for a dictionary with scores for each words, so for example the word "cool", +1, gets a positive score, the word "and" a neutral score, 0, and the word "bad" a negative score, -1.

Where can I find a dictionary with words and scores?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: http://mpqa.cs.pitt.edu/

Also, this is a duplicate of another SO post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188706/sentiment-analysis-dictionaries